# How do I install gropdf?

Tags: text-processing, drivers, pdf, groff

I am a new user of groff and want to generate pdf files with it. I know that the basic syntax is as follows:

```
    groff -ms inputcode.ms -T pdf > outputfile.pdf
```

But, when I try it, I get the following error message:

> groff: can't find `DESC' file groff:fatal error: invalid device` pdf'

Having done a great deal of research, I realized that I need a pdf driver, a basic package that was lacking in my installation of groff (I've installed groff it using apt-get). I have no idea why the driver was not included!!! Anyway, I would like to install such driver. I have searched for ways to do this, but have not found any. How do I do this?

PS: Groff must recognize the installed driver/package.

Comment: What Unix are you using?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 9... Thank you for helping. The problem is already resolved.

Comment: Related: [Export a man page in pdf](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/444767)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have only a basic groff installation. You can see this by finding the full pathname to the groff command:

```
command -v groff
```

It says `/usr/bin/groff`.  Use this to find which package it came from:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/groff
```

It says `groff-base`.  Look for other packages:

```
apt search groff
```

You just have to install the listed full groff package, which is just called `groff`:

```
sudo apt install groff
```

Comment: It's worked perfectly and I have learned a lot about how to manage packages ( I know it's simples, but...). Thanks a lot!